# How to retrieve span within a class name using vba and xml method

Tags: html, vba, xmlhttprequest

Given the following HTTP code from Nasdaq.com site:

```
<li class="dividend-history__summary-item" data-item="exDividendDate">
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__label">Ex-Dividend Date</span>
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__value"><span>05/26/2022</span></span>
</li>
<li class="dividend-history__summary-item" data-item="yield">
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__label">Dividend Yield</span>
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__value"><span>9.24%</span></span>
</li>
<li class="dividend-history__summary-item" data-item="annualizedDividend">
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__label">Annual Dividend</span>
  <span class="dividend-history__summary-item__value">$<span>0.72</span></span>
```

I am trying to retrieve the dividend percent defined by the class name "dividend-history__summary-item__value".  Here is my vba code:

```
Dim WEBSITE As String
Dim REQUEST As Object
Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDATA As String
Dim TICKER As String
Dim DIVYIELD As String

TICKER = UCase(Range("B3"))

WEBSITE = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/" & TICKER & "/dividend-history"

Set REQUEST = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
REQUEST.Open "GET", WEBSITE, False
REQUEST.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
'get web page
REQUEST.send
'store web page as raw data in HTMLDATA string
HTMLDATA = StrConv(REQUEST.responseBody, vbUnicode)
'Convert raw web data into HTML code
HTML.body.innerHTML = HTMLDATA

DIVYIELD = HTML.getElementsByClassName("dividend-history__summary- 
item__value").Item(0).innerHTML
**'Result in Msgbox = <span> &nbsp </span>**
MsgBox DIVYIELD
DIVYIELD = HTML.getElementsByClassName("dividend-history__summary- 
item__value").Item(0).innerText
MsgBox DIVYIELD
**'Result in Msgbox = blank**
```

I tried different item numbers but no luck.  I believe that class name is the only one on the page.  I tried two methods of setting intermediate objects:

```
Dim GETPERCENT As Object
Set GETPERCENT = HTML.getElementsByClassName("dividend-history__summary-item__value")
DIVYIELD = GETPERCENT.innerText
```

Got runtime error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method. Then tried replacing with this statement:

```
DIVYIELD = GETPERCENT.getElementById("span").Item(0).innerText
```

Got same runtime error 438
Also tried concatenating two methods together as seen on one of the examples in stackoverflow:

```
DIVYIELD = HTML.getElementsByClassName("dividend-history__summary- 
item__value").getElementById("span").Item(0).innerText
```

Got same runtime error 438
I feel like I am close but missing something.  Please help.

Comment: "span" is a tagname, not an id  Maybe try `HTML.getElementsByClassName("dividend-history__summary-item__value")(0).innerText`

Comment: That is the command I initially used in the VBA text above but result was blank.  When I used .innerhtml instead of .innertext, it showed <span> &nbsp </span>, so I am wondering if it isn't working because the variable &nbsp id not populated using this xml method.  the value I want shows when I do an inspect but not when retrieving the webpage with the xml method.

Comment: `&nbsp` is a space (specifically a non-breaking space) so it might have looked blank when you used innerText.

Comment: Did you do a view page source or an inspect item to see the page's html?

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I changed the macro to use the IE method so I could set IE.visible = True.  As I suspected the web page shell comes up but is unpopulated with data..  Somehow the data is inserted at some point after the macro analyzes it for data.  BTW, I did  "do Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE" to make sure the page was loaded before getting the data.  Has anyone else run into this situation before?

Comment: Please provide a test ticker and expected return value. Ticker values in url should also be lowercase not upper IIRC.